# Updating a C array while reading an input file

Tags: python, cython, arrays

I am now using cython to read an input file, convert the string to int and store them in a c array (instead of a list) to save space. The code I have looks like this:

```
cdef long p[10000000]
cdef long i
i = 0
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    temp = map(int, line.split())
    p[i] = temp[0]
    i = i + 1
f.close()
```

However, the program is always aborted when I refer to the array p. Somehow the array is not "defined" as the memory usage is very low. It works, however, if I'm doing

```
cdef i
for i in range(0, 1000):
    p[i] = i
```

Comment: What is the value of i when the program aborts?

Comment: You could use an `array.array()` if you are just worried about space

Comment: By the way, you can use enumerate instead of declaring `i` before and doing the increment "by hand".
Anyway, is it possible that the problem is that you assign a non-cdef long to the array? What if you do this: `temp=map(int, lines.rstrip().split())[0]; p[i]=temp` and you cdef temp also?

Comment: The problem is probably in the part of the code you did not include in your question, or how you execute it since the first part the code works perfectly on its own. I have tried with Cython 0.17 and had no problem. Could you give us more details on the error you get, the exact function you are using, and how you compile this code ?

Comment: How is space saved if you pre-allocate 10m elements? What happens if you have one more data element in you input? You should really be doing this in Python proper.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing this in Cython, not cPython? Reading from a file is an IO bound operation and you're unlikely to make significant speed gains by doing it in C.

Comment: You could use numpy: `arr = numpy.loadtxt(filename, dtype=long, usecols=(0,))`

Comment: Is this top-level module code or is this wrapped in a function? If the latter, and p is not global, p goes out of scope. Also, allocating 1M longs on stack is bad idea.

Comment: @Bakuriu, cython inserts explicit cast on your behalf, method assert's if incompatible Python type is assigned to C type.

Answer (score 1):

My guesses:

- the code you posted is actually wrapped in a function, in which case `p` is allocated on the stack and as soon as the given function returns, access to `p` is illegal.
- you don't check `i` for overflow, what happens if `i > 1000000`?
- trying to allocate 1M 8-byte integers on stack may be beyond what is allowed, check `ulimit -a`

Overall there is not enough information in the OP, e.g.:

- is that code top-level in module or content of a function?
- how is program aborted (SEGV?)
- referring to `p` in what context?
- what os/arch do you use?

I could not reproduce your problem with Python 2.7.3 Cython 0.17.2 gcc 4.7.2 linux 3.6.9 x86-64